# Slick-CodeGen for specific tables

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I am looking at the slick 2.1 code generation utility (working with legacy code).

http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/2.1.0/code-generation.html

I don't see a syntax which will allow me to run the code-gen on only a few specific tables.

So I added new tables, and I want to generate only those not everything else.

Is this possible?